# Query gives #1305 - FUNCTION database-name.LEN does not exist; WHY?

Tags: mysql

**EDIT3** [MySQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/21be8/3). I have made the example `MySQL` so you can see the actual problems. While I am expecting to have `Jamie Foxx, Christoph Waltz` in the `2 names` result it gives much more. Even though it is written the exact same way as it was in the `SQL` example where it return the names correctly. :/

**EDIT2** [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a46406/17). This is a much simpler version, but the logic is there. I need to have this working in `MySQL` as the fiddle is in `SQL`. When I just replace the `SQL` functions with `LENGTH` and `LOCATE` and test it with PhpMyAdmin it returns the entire content of the `actors` column, not just the first two names. I am even more confused now as the `LOCATE` is supposed to be equivalent to the `CHARINDEX`.

**EDIT1** *Oh, I just found it that neither `LEN` or `CHARINDEX` exist in `MySQL`. I think I can replace `LEN` with `LENGTH`, but I don't know what to do with the `CHARINDEX` I tried using `LOCATE` but the result is incorrect it gives the full content of the `actors` field. Any insight on this?

Another follow up on my previous questions. This should be the end of it though. I had part of the query that uses the `len` function working on SQL Fiddle, but as soon as I implemented it into the final query in my actual database I getting the function does not exist error. Listing all I consider related below:

**MySQL query**

```
SELECT 
title,
director,
thumb,
LEFT(actors, LEN(actors) - CHARINDEX(', ', actors))AS '2 names' 
FROM test 
WHERE MATCH (title, director, actors) AGAINST ('arc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**The error**

```
#1305 - FUNCTION database-name.LEN does not exist
```

**Setup**

```
OS: MAC OSX
SERVER: MAMP
DB ACCESS: PhpMyAdmin
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE test**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `director` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `actors` varchar(10000) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Jamie Foxx, Christoph Waltz, Leonardo DiCaprio, Kerry Washington, Samuel L. Jackson',
 `summary` text NOT NULL,
 `cover` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'http://localhost:8888/assets/OBS/img/uploads/covers-thumb/django_thumb.jpg',
 `thumb` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'http://localhost:8888/assets/OBS/img/uploads/covers-bug/django1_cover.jpg',
 `trailer` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'fnaojlfdUbs',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `myindex` (`title`,`director`,`actors`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I really don't understand why I am  getting this error, as the statement worked fine on SQL Fiddle. If you'd need any additional information just ask for it. Thank you all for reading and in advance for your replies.

BTW: Any chance it is caused by `actors varchar(10000)`?

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using in 5.0 [**LENGTH(str)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) exist not **LEN**

Comment: Could you append a link to this Sqlfiddle ? There is no build-in `len` function in MySql, there are `lenght` and `char-length` functions, check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Ahh. The old sqlfiddle.com trick of selecting the wrong make and model of RDMS! `LEN()` is a Microsoft SQL server function. Hate when that happens.

Comment: [**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b8eed/2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a built-in CHARINDEX() function.Instead you can use [**LOCATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) equivalent to charindex ,and instead of LEN you can use [**LENGTH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

```
SELECT 
title,
director,
thumb,
LEFT(actors, LENGTH(actors) - LOCATE(', ', actors))AS '2 names' 
FROM test 
WHERE MATCH (title, director, actors) AGAINST ('arc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[**See fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b8eed/2)

If you just want to show two actors name you can use [**SUBSTRING_INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT 
title,
director,
thumb,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(actors, ',', 2) AS '2 names' 
FROM test 
WHERE MATCH (title, director, actors) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[**See second fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b8eed/3)

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane [***See this fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b8eed/3) which shows two actors names

Comment: THAT IS IT! Wow, so many changes to get the same result from `SQL` to `MySQL`. Are you going to post it as an answer so I can accept? Or should I post it?